# Resolve ambiguity in results of SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Two tables have a column called "title" and so row['title'] is ambiguous and just seems to pick one of the results at random (PHP/MYSQL).
Is there a way around this or do I have to make sure my columns are distinctly named even when they are in different tables?

**EDIT :**
To be clear I need the title field from BOTH tables. The question is: After selecting with `table1.title`, `table2.title` How do I access them in `$row` as in 
`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` ? `$row['title']`  is ambiguous. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use column aliases in this case as explained [here](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/column-alias.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try [aliasing](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) the column:

```
SELECT A AS B
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

try syntax like this

```
 Select * from tableA where tableA.title=x
```